# How to test connection to Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, ec2-api-tools

My application is supposed to create new folder at Amazon S3 bucket and to put there some logs.
The problem is : it just does not happen.
S3 bucket exists (I created it before), but no new folder is seen there.

How can I test the problem? Are there any tools that can be useful?

I turned on Amazon S3 Bucket Logging (see here: http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--bucket-logging.html), but logs are aggregated once in hour... Then I'm looking for other ways/tools to test the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is a "flat" file system, meaning it does not have physical folders. "Folders" as you know are simply prefixes added to file names.

Just try to put the file over there, without ever thinking about folders, and see whether that works.

Comment: that is the point: I cannont put there neither folders nor files ( everything is object at Amazon, I've got it)

Comment: An object is nothing more, nothing less, than a file. Put an object and that should be it.

Comment: I tell you that I can't. I failed to do it

Answer (score 0):

s3cmd is fine:
http://s3tools.org/s3cmd